# Set headers and body of a response in express

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, fetch

I want to create a node server that receives an URL and return the result of the request to that URL.
If I send him `https://www.google.com` in the request I need to receive the result back.

I want to receive the statusCode, the headers and the body.
I want to be able to receive HTML and JSON or any other type of response.
I was able to modify the statusCode but not the rest, any help would be great.

```js
"use strict";

const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { fetch: requestUrl } = req.query;
  if (requestUrl) {
    try {
      const proxyResponse = await fetch(requestUrl);
      res.body = proxyResponse.body;
      res.statusCode = proxyResponse.status;
      res.send();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  } else {
    req.sendStatus(400);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening");
});
```

I tried to modify the headers using `res.set(proxyResponse.headers.raw());`
but I get `TypeError: Content-Type cannot be set to an Array`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const app = require("express")();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const {fetch: requestUrl} = req.query;
  if (requestUrl) {
    try {
        const proxyResponse = await fetch(requestUrl);
        res.statusCode = proxyResponse.status;

        // headers
        //get
        const headers = Array.from(proxyResponse.headers)
            // Be careful about content-encoding header!
            .filter(([key]) => !key.includes('content-encoding'))
            .reduce((headers, [key, value]) => ({[key]: value, ...headers}), {});
        //set
        res.set(headers);
        
        // body
        //get
        const body = await proxyResponse.text();
        //set
        res.send(body);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  } else {
    req.sendStatus(400);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening"));
```

Comment: care for some explanation?
Why are you eliminating the content-encoding from the headers?
Why there's no simple way of assigning the same header of the req to the response?

Comment: @OussamaBouthouri I test this on my machine and found that content-encoding header breaks rendering html on frontend side. It happens because `res.send(body);` with `await proxyResponse.text();` change encoding of original content, and if you try render this with old encoding - it fails